# GDB fails with "Python Exception <class 'RecursionError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded" error

Tags: gdb

I'm running g++ (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0 and GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1.

All I am doing is to try to run `use_count()` method of `std::shared_ptr`, which fails with the error

```
(gdb) p ptr.use_count()
Python Exception <class 'RecursionError'>: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Error while looking for matching xmethod workers defined in Python.
```

The following bash script reproduces the issue.

```
cat << EOF > main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>(0);
    std::cout << ptr.use_count() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
EOF

g++ -std=c++17 -g main.cc
./a.out
gdb -q a.out -ex "set confirm off" -ex "b 7" -ex "r" -ex "p ptr.use_count()" -ex "q"
```

By the way, LLDB executes the function without an issue. Is this a GDB bug or am I missing something?

--Edit 1--

As Mark suggested, I added `set python print-stack full` in gdb. The following is the output

```
(gdb) set python print-stack full
(gdb) p ptr.use_count()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../share/gcc/python/libstdcxx/v6/xmethods.py", line 777, in match
    worker = method.worker_class(class_type.template_argument(0))
  File "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../share/gcc/python/libstdcxx/v6/xmethods.py", line 733, in __init__
    SharedPtrUseCountWorker.__init__(self, elem_type)
  File "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../share/gcc/python/libstdcxx/v6/xmethods.py", line 733, in __init__
    SharedPtrUseCountWorker.__init__(self, elem_type)
  File "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/../../share/gcc/python/libstdcxx/v6/xmethods.py", line 733, in __init__
    SharedPtrUseCountWorker.__init__(self, elem_type)
  [Previous line repeated 995 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
Error while looking for matching xmethod workers defined in Python.
```

-- Edit 2 --

As ks1322 suggested, a temporary work around is to disable xmethod

```
(gdb) disable xmethod
(gdb) p ptr.use_count()
$1 = 1
```

Comment: Can you type `set python print-stack full` and then run the `p` command again?

Comment: As a workaround you can disable all xmethods with `disable xmethod`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I updated the body accordingly

Comment: Looks like a xmethod bug to me, which should probably be [reported to gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a GDB bug or am I missing something?

It is either GDB bug or [libstdc++ xmethods](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python/libstdcxx/v6/xmethods.py) bug. As a workaround you can disable all xmethods with `disable xmethod`.